# Convert table into a vector to use hist() on r

Tags: r, vector

I'm learning some of R this days, I have some data on a file:

```
0.7300719696546073 0.5508739992014652 0.2371535688287479
0.9359803887798046 0.8249035576959065 0.3715476175169042
0.3403916445508408 0.8036890953987708 0.8079012937499597
```

Just like that... (but way bigger)

```
data = read.table("data.txt")
```

In some operations I would like to have all the data on a single vector to use `hist(data)`
but I get: `'x' must be numeric`

I tried different stuff like `as.vector(data)` or `lapply(c(data), as.numeric)` but nothing works.

Would you give me a hand?

SOLVED: unlist(data)
PS: Expected to not work since I have a table of 100(cols)*5000(rows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
unlist(data)
```

will do the trick. This is an easy way to transform a data frame to a vector.

---

With your data:

```
data <- read.table(text="
0.7300719696546073 0.5508739992014652 0.2371535688287479
0.9359803887798046 0.8249035576959065 0.3715476175169042
0.3403916445508408 0.8036890953987708 0.8079012937499597")

unlist(data)
```

The result is a vector (with named elements) :

```
      V11       V12       V13       V21       V22       V23       V31       V32       V33 
0.7300720 0.9359804 0.3403916 0.5508740 0.8249036 0.8036891 0.2371536 0.3715476 0.8079013
```

If you don't want to have the names, use the argument `use.names = FALSE` in `unlist`:

```
unlist(data, use.names = FALSE)

[1] 0.7300720 0.9359804 0.3403916 0.5508740 0.8249036 0.8036891 0.2371536 0.3715476 0.8079013
```

Answer (score 2):

`as.numeric(as.matrix(data))` will do it.  Not esp. elegant!  Also, be careful about calling your data, data.  You can use `str(data)` to see how your data is structured.  However, `read.table` returns a `data frame`.

Compared to the answer of `unlist(data)`, this method doesn't get you the automatically constructed variable names (V1... Vn).